# How to get the advertising stop event when using bluetooth low energy (BLE)?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to write a app to do advertise in android BLE. I want to get the "when advertising stop event", what should I do? I need to do something like: when advertising timeout, do something. But I can I get the timeout or stop event?

Comment: What is an "advertising stop" event?  If your app is performing the advertising, then doesn't it stop when you tell it to stop?  Please add more detail to your question.   Also post what research you have already done and where your confusion arises.

Comment: @rothloup I want it like, start advertising for 30 second. if no scanner connect to it, then stop advertising. Like a timeout. Then how do i know it is timeout or not when it is timeout?

Comment: so write timer or handler what's problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, which indicate that you want to advertise for a bit, then stop, your best bet is to use a `Handler`.

In the `Runnable()` code, you could either set a flag, as I've done below, or call some other method to handle a more complex operation.  If you get a device that connects before the timeout expires, you can call `mHandler.removeCallBacks()`.

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class thisClase {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    boolean timedOut = false;
    public static final int TIMEOUT = 30*1000; //30 second timeout

    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Put your code to stop advertisting here.
            timedOut = true;
        }
    }

    public void startAdvert() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, TIMEOUT);

        //Put code to start advertising here.
        timedOut=false;
        //Start Advertising.
    }

    //Call this method when a device connects to cancel the timeout.
    public void whenDeviceConnects() {
        //Cancel the runnable.
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
}
```